# Per-key blocking Map in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I'm dealing with some third-party library code that involves creating expensive objects and caching them in a `Map`. The existing implementation is something like

```
lock.lock()
try {
    Foo result = cache.get(key);
    if (result == null) {
        result = createFooExpensively(key);
        cache.put(key, result);
    }
    return result;
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Obviously this is not the best design when `Foos` for different `keys` can be created independently.

My current hack is to use a `Map` of `Futures`:

```
lock.lock();
Future<Foo> future;
try {
    future = allFutures.get(key);
    if (future == null) {
        future = executorService.submit(new Callable<Foo>() {
            public Foo call() {
                return createFooExpensively(key);
            }
        });
        allFutures.put(key, future);
    }
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}

try {
    return future.get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new MyRuntimeException(e);
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    throw new MyRuntimeException(e);
}
```

But this seems... a little hacky, for two reasons:

1. The work is done on an arbitrary pooled thread. I'd be happy to have the work
   done on the first thread that tries to get that particular key, especially since
   it's going to be blocked anyway.
2. Even when the `Map` is fully populated, we still go through `Future.get()` to get
   the results. I expect this is pretty cheap, but it's ugly.

What I'd like is to replace `cache` with a `Map` that will block gets *for a given key* until that key has a value, but allow other gets meanwhile. Does any such thing exist? Or does someone have a cleaner alternative to the `Map` of `Futures`?

Comment: Store the key objects in a `ConcurrentHashMap` and lock on the key objects themselves?  If the keys are intrinsics (int, `String`, etc) wrap them.

Comment: This almost sounds like you want a Guava [`Striped`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html), which sort of acts as a map from objects to locks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creating a lock per key sounds tempting, but it may not be what you want, especially when the number of keys is large.

As you would probably need to create a dedicated (read-write) lock for each key, it has impact on your memory usage. Also, that fine granularity may hit a point of diminishing returns given a finite number of cores if concurrency is truly high.

ConcurrentHashMap is oftentimes a good enough solution in a situation like this. It provides normally full reader concurrency (normally readers do not block), and updates can be concurrent up to the level of concurrency level desired. This gives you pretty good scalability. The above code may be expressed with ConcurrentHashMap like the following:

```
ConcurrentMap<Key,Foo> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
...
Foo result = cache.get(key);
if (result == null) {
  result = createFooExpensively(key);
  Foo old = cache.putIfAbsent(key, result);
  if (old != null) {
    result = old;
  }
}
```

The straightforward use of ConcurrentHashMap does have one drawback, which is that multiple threads may find that the key is not cached, and each may invoke createFooExpensively(). As a result, some threads may do throw-away work. To avoid this, you would want to use the memoizer pattern that's mentioned in "Java Concurrency in Practice".

But then again, the nice folks at Google already solved these problems for you in the form of [CacheBuilder](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html):

```
LoadingCache<Key,Foo> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().
  concurrencyLevel(32).
  build(new CacheLoader<Key,Foo>() {
    public Foo load(Key key) {
      return createFooExpensively(key);
    }
  });

...
Foo result = cache.get(key);
```

Comment: Thanks -- the `Memoizer` section in JCiP walks through almost exactly this scenario. Should have RTFB I guess. :)

Comment: (And I'll remember `CacheBuilder` when I'm back in our own code with access to Guava.)

Comment: Someone lifted this answer and created a blog post https://newbedev.com/per-key-blocking-map-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You can use [funtom-java-utils](https://github.com/funtom-io/funtom-java-utils) - [PerKeySynchronizedExecutor](http://funtom-io.github.io/funtom-java-utils/releases/0.1/javadoc/io/funtom/util/concurrent/PerKeySynchronizedExecutor.html).

It will create a lock for each key but will clear it for you immediately when it becomes unused.

It will also grantee memory visibility between invocations with the same key, and is designed to be very fast and minimize the contention between invocations off different keys.

Declare it in your class:

```
final PerKeySynchronizedExecutor<KEY_CLASS> executor = new PerKeySynchronizedExecutor<>();
```

Use it:

```
Foo foo = executor.execute(key, () -> createFooExpensively());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Cache {

    private static final Set<String> lockedKeys = new HashSet<>();

    private void lock(String key) {
        synchronized (lockedKeys) {
            while (!lockedKeys.add(key)) {
                try {
                    lockedKeys.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    log.error("...");
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void unlock(String key) {
        synchronized (lockedKeys) {
            lockedKeys.remove(key);
            lockedKeys.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public Foo getFromCache(String key) {
        try {
            lock(key);

            Foo result = cache.get(key);
            if (result == null) {
                result = createFooExpensively(key);
                cache.put(key, result);
            }
            return result;
            //For different keys it is executed in parallel.
            //For the same key it is executed synchronously.

        } finally {
            unlock(key);
        }
    }

}
```

- **key** can be not only a 'String' but any class with correctly overridden 'equals' and 'hashCode' methods.
- **try-finally** - is very important - you must guarantee to unlock waiting threads after your operation even if your operation threw exception.
- It will not work if your back-end is distributed across **multiple servers/JVMs**.