# Design: Object with single use?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

**Context**

I have a class called `ImageLoader`.

When I call ImageLoader's `getPicture( pictureID )`, if the picture is not cached, I store `pictureID` in an instance variable, create a new thread which eventually calls my `callback()` function in this same `ImageLoader` class.  `callback()` then uses this `pictureID` as the key to cache the picture.

**Problem**

Do you see the pickle?
If I call `getPicture( somePictureID )` twice in a row, and the `callback()` function for the first call hasn't happened yet, I will overwrite the previous `pictureID` which the `callback()` function will use. (See the code below if you still don't see the pickle.)

Now I know you're thinking, why don't I just add a little synchronization on the variable to make it thread-safe?

Because who knows how long the thread querying the picture will take, and that could really slow down the whole process of loading multiple images.

**How I'm Thinking of Solving It**

So my bright idea is to create an inner class that servers as a slave and only has a single use.  I execute some function in this slave class once, and I never reuse the object.

**Question**

Is this an appropriate approach to solving this kind of problem? I feel like this might fall into some pattern I'm not aware of. If I'm totally off the mark with this one, can you suggest another solution?

**Simplified Code**

```
//the instance variable with a race condition
private int pictureID

//loads the image associated with the pictureID
public void getPicture( int pictureID )
{
     Bitmap bitmap = cache.get( pictureID );
     if ( bitmap != null )
     {
         //load image
         return; 
     }

     int post_params[] = { pictureID, /* more parameters */ };

     this.pictureID = pictureID; //PROBLEM: race condition!
     new HttpRequest( this ).execute( post_params ); //starts new thread and queries server
}

 //gets called when the query finishes, json contains my image
 public void callback( JSONObject json )
 {
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap( json ); //made up method to simplify code
    cache.put( this.pictureID, bitmap ); //PROBLEM: race condition!

    //load image
 }
```

Comment: How about passing `pictureId` as parameter to your `callback()` method?

Comment: @RohitJain That's a good suggestion not knowing other details about my project, but I don't think that's a good solution for me. The reason is this:
  `new HttpRequest(this).execute( params );`.  This line of code takes a `Callee` (interface) as an argument and calls the `callback()` function.  Passing the pictureID into the HttpRequest constructor just so it can send it back through the `callback()` function doesn't really make much sense semantically.

Comment: "Do you see the pickle?"  No.  Post some code that will help us to see it.

Comment: How would you expect anyone to know whether a solution **makes sense semantically** to your situation, unless you depict your situation properly. Rather you could show some code, that would save you from recieving some absurd solution.

Comment: @jameslarge I added code to show the problem.

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer at the moment, but I think you're looking for the [Memoizer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). _Java Concurrency in Practice_ explains it it in detail, but Guava's [Suppliers](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html) or [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) will do the heavy lifting for you. See e.g. "[Per-key blocking map in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821767/per-key-blocking-map-in-java)".

Comment: ...okay, I [added an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28682259/27358).

Comment: What about having an ImageLoader that returns picture Futures? Internally, it maintains a map from the URL to the future that's your cache. You then have a pool of workers that do the actual fetching, and they set the future when they complete. Kinda like a CompletionService.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann You should post an answer with a small code snippet to show what you're saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this looks like a classic case of the [Memoizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) pattern, and the easiest way to use it is probably Guava's [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html), something like:

```
private LoadingCache<Integer, Image> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().
        build(new CacheLoader<Integer, Image>() {
            @Override
            public Image load(Integer key) throws Exception {
                return httpGetImageExpensively(key);
            }
        });

public Image getPicture(int pictureId) {
   return cache.getUnchecked(pictureId); // blocks until image is in cache
}
```

Now, the HTTP request will happen in the first thread that calls `getPicture()` for a given ID; subsequent callers with that ID will block until the first thread has put the image in cache, but you can make multiple concurrent requests for different IDs.

Things to think about:

- How slow is loading going to be? Do you need a timeout mechanism?
- What if the loading fails? The `cache.get()` method throws a (checked) `ExecutionException`, which is why I'm using `getUnchecked()` instead, but that just throws an (unchecked) `UncheckedExecutionException` instead. If possible, I would do most of the error handling in `httpGetImageExpensively()`, and think through the possible cases there (bad ID, DNS failure, etc.) but the callers of `getPicture()` will still need to deal with that somehow.
- If loading a given ID fails once, is it going to fail every time? If so, you probably don't want to waste time re-HTTP-GETting it every time, and you need to add a mechanism for that. Note though that the question of whether it's worth retrying may have a different answer for different types of failure.
- This implementation blocks each calling thread until there's an image ready for it. Is that workable for this application? If not, you may want to replace `getPicture()` with something a little fancier that takes an image handler callback object or lambda, and then internally put the actual calls to `httpGetImageExpensively()` on an `ExecutorService`, so `getPicture()` can return immediately. (Depending on the application, there may be other issues, e.g. in a Swing app it might be desirable to invoke the callback on the event dispatch thread.)

Comment: This is pretty cool.  I'll probably accept this later if I don't get any better answers. Gave you an upvote for now. I won't incorporate this into my project today (because deadlines), but it's definitely something I'll look back at when I run into this problem again.

Answer (score 1):

A thought besides: Thread creation is expensive.

1. Create a thread pool (The Java API has support for this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)
2. Derive the `Runnable` class to implement your "task".
3. Submit your Runnables to the Thread Pool Executor service.

`pictureID` should be an instance variable of for your Runnable-derived class. Your Runnable-derived class can be (but needn't be) implemented as inner class of your `ImageLoader` class.

**EDIT: Example.**

```
some_perhaps_inner_class MyRunable implements Runnable {
    private int someImportantId;

    MyRunnable(int someImportantId) {
        this.someImportantId = someImportantId;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doTheTimeConsumingStuffHere();
    }
}

ExecutorService myThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
myThreadPool.submit(new MyRunnable(someImportantId));
```

Details depend on your special needs. Take a look in the Java API to read further.

Comment: I'm not a pro with thread pools, so it'd be cool if you could provide a small code snippet to see better what you're saying.

Comment: This is also very cool.  If I understand this correctly, it's similar to my inner class solution in the sense that you're instantiating single use objects, but you're using threads from beginning to end making it entirely asynchronous. And the thread pool just makes it more efficient. (Sorry if my understanding's a little off, just read up on thread pools for about 30 seconds.)

Comment: >> it's similar to my inner class solution << Correct. >> but you're using threads from beginning to end << I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but a) submit is an asynchronous call, and b) The thread pool holds 3 threads and assigns to them the submitted Runnables (on each thread one Runnable after another).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than dealing with callbacks, this returns a `Future` of the bitmap that you can block on until it's ready. If you depend on multiple bitmaps and don't want to block separately on all of them, I'd retrofit this to work with Guava Futures.

```
public class AsyncMemoizingImageLoader {
    private final ConcurrentMap<Integer, Future<Bitmap>> bitmaps = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

    // TODO: shutdown executor when complete

    public Future<Bitmap> getPicture(final int pictureID) {
        if (!bitmaps.contains(pictureID)) {
            RunnableFuture<Bitmap> future = new FutureTask<Bitmap>(new Callable<Bitmap>() {
                @Override public Bitmap call() throws Exception {
                    // HTTP stuff goes here.  pictureID is accessible in this scope
                }
            });

            // This bit is key; only submit the future for completion if the
            // picture id isn't already being processed
            if (bitmaps.putIfAbsent(pictureID, future) == null) {
                executor.submit(future);
            }
        }

        return bitmaps.get(pictureID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you comment this a bit more (for someone like myself who didn't even know FutureTasks existed)? I'm reading up on them right now, but I'm still trying to understand how this achieves the same result without running into the race condition on the pictureID.

Comment: FutureTasks aren't actually completed when they're created. In the case of the race condition, one task is memoized and added to the work queue, and the other is discarded. `map.putIfAbsent(pictureID, future)` will only return `null` the first time it's called for a given ID. On subsequent calls, the first task that was submitted will be returned.

Comment: Wow this is super cool too now that I understand it.  Thanks for breaking it down.

Comment: The one gotcha is you have to do `getPicture(42).get()` (and this is a blocking call) to actually have a `Bitmap`. If this is a problem for what you're doing, you'll probably want to check out Guava.

Answer (score 0):

How HttpRequest knows which picture we need? We do not send any information about it (pictureId is private field). If it is not related (pictureId - requested picture) just use priority queue.

```
//queue contains pictures id queue to load
private Queue<Integer> pictureIDQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();

//loads the image associated with the pictureID
public void getPicture( int pictureID )
{
     Bitmap bitmap = cache.get( pictureID );
     if ( bitmap != null )
     {
         //load image
         return; 
     }

     synchronized(pictureIDQueue)
     {
         this.pictureIDQueue.add(pictureID);
     }
     new HttpRequest( this ).execute(); //starts new thread and queries server
}

 //gets called when the query finishes, json contains my image
 public void callback( JSONObject json )
 {
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap( json ); //made up method to simplify code

    synchronized(pictureIDQueue)
    {
        cache.put( this.pictureIDQueue.poll(), bitmap );
    }
    //load image
 }
```

Comment: I don't think the network guarantees pictures will be retrieved in order.  For example, a 2nd http request may complete before the first one and will break your solution. 
And emitting the picture id from the parameters in the http request was my mistake when simplifying the code.  I'll edit it.

Comment: Ok i know about it, but you didn't pass any parameter to HttpRequest, and pictureId is private filed. So how HttpRequest object know which picture should load?

Comment: I edited my code to pass in the id to the HttpRequest.  I left it out by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this:

```
private Map<Integer, Bitmap> cache = new HashMap<Integer,Bitmap>();
private Queue<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<Thread>();
//the instance variable with a race condition
private int pictureID;

//loads the image associated with the pictureID
public void getPicture(final int pmPictureID )
{
     Bitmap bitmap = cache.get( pictureID );
     if ( bitmap != null )
     {
         //load image
         return; 
     }

     int post_params[] = { pictureID, /* more parameters */ };
     final ImageLoader instance = this;

     Thread currentThread = new Thread()
     {
         @Override
         public void run()
         {
             pictureID = pmPictureID;
             new HttpRequest(instance).execute( post_params ); //starts new thread and queries server
         }
     };

     if(threads.size() > 0)
     {
         threads.add(currentThread);
     }
     else
     {
         currentThread.start();
     }
}

 //gets called when the query finishes, json contains my image
 public void callback( JSONObject json )
 {
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap( json ); //made up method to simplify code
    cache.put( this.pictureID, bitmap ); //PROBLEM: race condition!

    if(threads.peek() != null)
    {
        threads.poll().start();
    }
    //load image
 }
```